# pyplot x-axis tick mark spacing is not centered with all columns

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, bins

I'm struggling with what I hope is a misspecification of the pyplot histogram function.  As you see in the image, the x-axis tick marks are not centered consistently on the columns as per the align='mid' parameter. If necessary, I will upload the data file to Dropbox.
Thanks for you help !

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

data = DRA_size_males_s

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
ax.hist(data, facecolor='blue', edgecolor='gray', bins=25, rwidth=1.10, align='mid')


bins=[1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.9,2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,3.1,3.2,3.5,3.6,3.8] 
ax.set_xticks(bins)

ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_xlabel('DRA Sizes(mm)')

ax.set_title('Frequencies of DRA Sizes in Males (mm)')

plt.show()
```

[image: pyplot histogram]

Here is the data array used to create the histogram:
1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.7, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plt.hist`'s `align="mid"` argument centers the bars of the histogram in the middle between the bin edges - this is in fact the usual way of plotting a histogram.

In order for the histogram to use predefined bin edges you need to supply those bin edges to the `plt.hist` function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 2.0, 
        2.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 
        2.7, 2.7, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3.8]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)

bins=[1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.9,2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,3.1,3.2,3.5,3.6,3.8]

ax.hist(data, bins=bins, facecolor='blue', edgecolor='gray', rwidth=1, align='mid') 
ax.set_xticks(bins)

ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_xlabel('DRA Sizes(mm)')
ax.set_title('Frequencies of DRA Sizes in Males (mm)')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you !  This gets me much closer but I'm confused why the data values of 3.6 and 3.8 are combined into one bin with a single frequency value of 2 (which is correct) when all of the other values have their own bin.

Comment: `bins` is the list of bin edges. All values that are between bin edges are included in the same bin, `bins[i] <= x < bins[i+1]`. Except for the last bin, which is closed, `bins[n-1] <= x <= bins[n]`.

Comment: Thank again !  Maybe I haven't done enough research about other approaches but I'm surprised that there is not a way to have a one-to-one rendering of x-axis value to histogram bar and be able to center that value relative to the histogram bar.  Please confirm this and I will accept your answer.  Thanks again for your time and insight !

Comment: Maybe there is some misunderstanding at some point. Almost any kind of 2D plot is possible with matplotlib. The above is a solution to what I understood being the question. What exactly do you mean by *"one-to-one rendering of x-axis value to histogram bar and be able to center that value relative to the histogram bar"*? This seems contradictory. Do you e.g. want the label of the first bin to be 1.45?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear.  For example, At the left most side of the histogram, 1.4 is a value that occurs 3 times and 1.5 is a value that occurs 2 times.  I'd like the 1.4 and 1.5 labels to be centered under their respective histogram bars.  Similarly, on the right side of the histogram, 3.6 is a value that occurs 1 time and 3.8 is a value that occurs 1 time. I'd like 3.6 and 3.8 to have their own bars, both indicating a frequency of 1, and have the value labels centered under their respective histogram bars.  Looks like I may be confused about how bins are used. Thanks !

Comment: Do you want equally sized bins now? Then why is the other answer not exactly what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `bins` with a `range` of values minus a small offset as in the following example.

```
In [100]: x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 3, 1, 7, 4, 5, 8, 8, 9, 7, 7, 3])

In [101]: len(x)
Out[101]: 16

In [102]: bins = np.arange(10) - 0.5

In [103]: plt.hist(x, facecolor='blue', edgecolor='gray', bins=bins, rwidth=2, alpha=0.75)
```

Now, the bin numbers will be `center` aligned.

[image: center aligned hist plot]

Comment: Thank you kmario but I'd like to see the x-axis bins associated with the discrete decimal point values. Your suggestion worked but playing around with some variations either created x-axis integer values or summed the frequencies within various ranges of the decimal values.  I edited my question to include the raw data.